# How to push notifications to a browser window?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a Django application which does calculations which runs in the background. The calculations take anything between 5 seconds to 2 minutes.

I am running these on celery. And it is updating a table in the database.

I am doing autorefesh of a DIV on a page every 2 seconds, which essentially does a SQL query. That means a number of unnecessary SQL queries till some data is displayed. Needless to say this is something that is increasing load on the database.

Is there a way to trigger the refresh only when the table is updated?

Comment: Is'nt there a way like how Meteor JS does where an update to the database shows up on the client window too?

Answer (score 1):

If the background task is assigned to a specific user, you could use session data to indicate that task has completed. In your Ajax function, you could look at this session data, and only look at the database when you have indication that this is completed:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/

Another solution would be to use a system file, used for synchronization. For example:

- The file is created when the background task is created, with start date and time. You may add further information like the user that requested it.
- As long as the file is present (With a further check for timeout, checking the data from the file), no need to look at the database.
- If the file is not present, you know that the request has completed and you can look at the database to update.

This file may also be accessible as an Url (To avoid the Ajax request)

Comment: I am doing this, but still is there not way like that in MeteorJs or some JS based full stack

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use Jquery and ajax to do the request using this..

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Hope it helps you